# Pygame Error: pygame has no attribute scrren

Tags: python, attributeerror

I am fairly new to python, so please help me out

[Image 1 is my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xmp5S.png)

[Image 2 is the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6eqUm.png)

Comment: Please provide your code and error in text format and not image. Also try to explain what you were trying to do, where are you stuck and what output do you expect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using variable screen but you have never initialised it. Looking at the code it is quite apparent that you should replace screen with the display and it should work

Comment: What do you mean by "replace screen with the display", (Sorry as I said, i am relatively new to this)

Comment: Wherever you have written screen change it to display

Comment: Example screen.blit should be changed to display.blit